# Is there a way in python to loop multiple key value pairs in a dict in single iteration of a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.6

I have the following example code and was interested if there was a way in Python to loop multiple key value pairs in a single loop iteration? If you see my example I have a dictionary with four key value pairs is there a way in python to loop this in a single pass?

```
my_dict = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3', 'key4':'value4'}

count = 1
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print('the count is {} the key is {} and the value is {}'.format(count, key, value))

    count += 1
```

---

```
the count is 1 the key is key4 and the value is value4
the count is 2 the key is key3 and the value is value3
the count is 3 the key is key1 and the value is value1
the count is 4 the key is key2 and the value is value2
```

---

expected return data would look like this

```
iteration count 1 - key1 value1, key2 value2, key3 value3, key4 value4
```

Comment: Is this not a single loop? What do you really want?

Comment: What I mean to say is a single loop with a single iteration in the loop. If you see the count the iteration count is four. I was trying to do this in a single iteration.

Comment: A loop with single iteration is not a loop, but simply a statement

Comment: What would you want to do in this single iteration? What would the loop iterations return other than the whole dict itself? Which you can get without looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep the current index.

```
import os

out = 'count: {}, key: {}, val: {}'
my_dict = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3', 'key4':'value4'}
os.linesep.join([out.format(c, *kv) for c, kv in enumerate(my_dict.items())])
```

Output:

```
count: 0, key: key3, val: value3
count: 1, key: key2, val: value2
count: 2, key: key1, val: value1
count: 3, key: key4, val: value4
```

**Example with condition:**

To answer the question in your comment, if you want to add or not items depending on a condition (btw, more `if` are possible):

```
[(c, *kv) for c, kv in enumerate(my_dict.items()) if c % 0 and len(kv[1]) < 5)
```

Also consider...

```
def do_something(c, kv):
    key, value = kv
    if key == 'key1':
        pass  # do something

    # somewhere return True or False depending on your logic

[(c, *kv) for c, kv in enumerate(my_dict.items()) if do_something(c, kv)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. But just another question is there a way to add an if condition to this? for example if key == 'key1' do something